# Errors in the reclassification using r.reclass tool

Tags: qgis, raster, reclassify

I am trying to reclassify a raster with daily precipitation values in Spain.

[image]

I use the following rules to reclasify:

0.0000 thru 0.0997 = 1

0.0998 thru 0.2553 = 2

0.2554 thru 0.8224 = 3

0.8225 thru 1.3699 = 4

1.3700 thru 1.5211 = 5

1.5212 thru 10.0000 = 6

I had a result, but it is aleatory, it does not fit the rules. There is cells that must be in a class, and they are in another. There is no cuts in the rules I specified.
[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: Your raster values are from 5.59482 to 317.2378, your classification is from 0 to 10 - so I'm not sure what you expect the result to look like. You must provide more details, otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: Sorry I confuse the raster layer. That was not the original. I will correct the image. The original values were between 0.06 - 3.52

Comment: Try to change the layer simbology to unique values

Comment: I tried but, same result. Anyway I don't understand why the simbology could affect the values or the reclass algorithm.